# How do I stop Git from automatically adding embedded repositories?

Tags: git

We have a large repository that needs to have two repositories nested inside it, like this:

```
Root
+- .git
+- Child1
   +- .git
+- Child2
   +- .git
```

We've recently run into a problem where running `git add .` causes Git to add both these repositories as embedded repositories. We don't want this. I want Git to ignore them.  ***Is there a Git config setting I can set to disable this behavior?***

We can add the child directory names to the .gitignore file:

```
Child1
Child2
```

But that will cause all directories/files named `Child1` and `Child2` in the whole repository to be ignored. We tried

```
Child1/**
Child2/**
```

but Git still embeds the repositories with `git add`.

Comment: There is no `.gitconfig` file (well, there is a `$HOME/.gitconfig`, unless you are using the fancier `$XDG_HOME` thing, but that's in `$HOME` or `$XDG_HOME`). Did you mean `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `gitignore` man pages:

```
   ·   A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example,
       "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".
```

So, change your .gitignore file to contain `/Child1` and `/Child2`, and you should have what you asked for.

However, another solution might be to actually make the two child repositories into real git submodules. That will have the added bonus of automatically getting those submodules into each synced "main" repo, and stricter version control (each commit in the main repo will have a well-specified submodule state). Depending on your exact situation, this may or may not be a good/convenient idea.